# Get currently open webpage in Internet Explorer in Java

Tags: java, internet-explorer

Is there a way to get the URL of the Website which is currently open in Internet Explorer in Java? Some Library would be ok, but it should be open source in this case.

Edit to clear things up:
My Standard Java Program runs on a Computer. Then I want to check if there is an Internet Explorer open on the same Machine. Then i want to get the URL currently open.

Comment: By "in Java" you mean in a JVM running on the same computer as the browser?

Comment: you want to know it in your servlet, in your jsp, in some class using your favorite web framework (jsf, struts, spring...)?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use Java? It's a server-side technology; maybe you can use JavaScript for that

Comment: @CarlosGavidia well i have to. Its a project requirement